# How to make a flashing image animation?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` with `alpha=0` by default. So it acts as an invisible overlay on another image.

On click, I want to create an animation that shows the overlay image for 200ms, and then hides it again.

The following does work in general, but only a single time! Why?

```
final ImageView flash = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flash);

flash.animate()
        .alpha(255) //make visible
        .setDuration(200)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                flash.setImageAlpha(0); //hide again
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're setting 2 different alpha values, the first one is View's alpha, but when you end the animation you set the ImageView class alpha to 0, so if you start the animation again, the View alpha is 1.0f but the image alpha will be 0 and you see nothing.
change it to

```
flash.animate()
        .alpha(1.f)
        .setDuration(200)
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                flash.setAlpha(0.f);
            }
        });
```

`View` (and therefore `ImageView`) has a method `setAlpha(float)`, `ImageView` adds also another method `setAlpha(int)`, which is deprecated because it's confusing as hell and now it's been renamed to `setImageAlpha(int)`. the animation will call `View`'s `setAlpha(float)`

Comment: I wish it was the only confusing thing when coding Android xD